# Let's get critical: Jun 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Aviation Stack Exchange](http://aviation.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I have had enough of you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one cares.

Comment: ... for more context, and fyi, the community team here at SE doesn't actually use these self-evaluations for anything anymore. It __DOES NOT affect graduation__. It's just busy work for the community at this point, and we're discussing getting rid of them entirely.

Comment: Yet I am still curious to see the results of the self-evaluation reviews. It may not affect graduation but I think it is a useful tool to see where we can improve. I find that many people here are very constructive in analysing and improving the way this site works. The self evaluation is a helpful tool to support those efforts.

Comment: @BretCopeland That's great. Now I'll stop feeling bad for not spending more than 30 seconds in doing the evaluation.